# WinSCP script will not exit after error, even with "option batch abort"

Tags: cmd, batch-processing, winscp

For some reason when my network drops my script will not abort.

Here's the command:

```
"%~dp0\winscp.exe" /console /script="script.txt" 
exit
```

and the script.txt:

```
option batch abort 
option confirm off 
open ftp://user:pass@ftp.site.com/ 
cd /directory/ 
synchronize local
exit
```

When I pull my network cable (to test for network drop) I get:

```
The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found. 
Connection failed. 
(A)bort, (R)econnect (5 s): 
.. 
(A)bort, (R)econnect (0 s): Reconnect
```

It will continue to try and reconnect indefinitely.

Why doesn't the script auto abort? I am using `option batch abort`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error is recoverable, so WinSCP keeps trying to resume the transfer even with the `option batch abort` as [documented](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/scriptcommand_option):

> ...
>   When batch mode is set to `on` any choice prompt is automatically replied negatively. Unless the prompt has a different default answer (such as a default “Reconnect” answer for a reconnect prompt), in what case the default answer is used (after a short time interval). See also a `reconnecttime` option below.
>   A value `abort` is like the `on`. ...

As mentioned above, you can configure, how long WinSCP tries to reconnect using the `option reconnecttime`. By default WinSCP tries to reconnect for 2 minutes in the `on`/`abort` mode.

*Note that WinSCP used to reconnect indefinitely in older versions, by default. You must be using some old version.*

Comment: Grabbed a beta copy, thanks! Promise I'll read more next time :D